# Output dir command to a file with spaces in the start

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Have a quick question as below:

```
dir /b *. >>Index.txt
```

The above command can output all the current directories in a list into text file called `index.txt`.

However, the list are on the leftmost of each line, can we have some space at the beginning of each output lines at the `index.txt`?

I am looking for a batch file solution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: DOS is very different from the Windows cmd (for example it doesn't have `for /f`). Don't tag DOS unless you're really running the command in DOS

Comment: `dir /b *.` does not output all the current directories in a list! `Dir /B/AD` will output all of the directories within the top level of the current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending upon your requirements, you could use something like this:

```bat
@(For /F "EOL=|Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/AD') Do @Echo         %%A)>"Index.txt"
```

Or perhaps you would prefer to right align it too:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "pad=                        "
(   For /F "EOL=|Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/AD') Do ( Set "line=%pad%%%A"
        Call Echo=%%line:~-24%%))>"Index.txt"
```

*The latter example may need adjusting according to the number of characters in your directory names.*